# Hit CURL after successfully order in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I want to make a CURL call after a successful product order by a user in `prestashop`.

Previously I used a hook when user completed successfully payment, then a CURL call executed. (Otherwise nothing happened.) Now I want to change it to after execute after a successful order. What hook should I use?

Comment: You need to explain what you have tried (and ideally what those failed attempts resulted in), in addition to what you want.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford: Thanks for your reply. Currently, i used orderConfirmation hook called when user done payment successfully for product then CURL hit. But now i want two cases first after successfully payment and second after order of product with voucher code.

Comment: I think you included all of that in the original question. Is there code you can share? What have you tried in concrete terms?

Answer (score 1):

`actionValidateOrder` called during the new order creation process, right after it has been created.